# error found while checking files before installing from usb stick

Tags: system-installation

I have a new laptop and I want to install ubuntu on it as the only OS. I made a usb bootable drive with ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with [this tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#3-launch-startup-disk-creator). I tried to boot from it, but before I got to the install menu it reported one wrong file.

I didn't want to install without checking, so I went back to my old laptop (ubuntu 18.04 LTS), verified the iso image and then made the bootable usb again. <s>I then ran md5checksum in the usb drive and it found no errors.</s> (ETA: I double checked and it did actually find an error, I just failed to notice it.)

When I tried installing again, it found an error in one file again. I installed ubuntu without problems, but before I set everything up, I'd like to know whether I should go through the whole process again and if so, how I can fix the error in the file.

ETA following the instructions in the answer below I found that the non matching file is `./boot/grub/efi.img`

## Conclusion

I checked my previous iso file again with:

```
$ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK
ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
```

So previously I did have a correct iso and an incorrect usb drive. I downloaded the iso file again, checked it, again ok, then redid the bootable drive and now there were no errors.

I'm now in the process of installing my new laptop, thanks for the help!

Comment: @guiverc thank you for commenting, I added in the correct versions.

Comment: Please tell us **which file** is reported as failing. And please tell us how you created the USB boot drive - **which method/tool** that you used.

Comment: @sudodus I added a link to to the tutorial I used for creating the usb drive (I made it on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS laptop), but I cannot tell you which file has an error, because it reports this error before going into the install menu as one sentence (something like, one error found, you can encounter problems), and then automatically goes into the install menu without interaction from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Help to find what is wrong

When you have verified the iso file with `md5sum`, you can be sure that it is correctly downloaded.

Using the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator should be very reliable because it is a cloning method. So it is strange, that you get an error when verifying one file. (It does not happen for me when booting into the same Ubuntu desktop 20.04.1 LTS when cloned.)

Method to identify the failing file:

- Boot into a live session 'Try Ubuntu' from the USB boot drive.
- Run the following commands (you can copy and paste from this window to a terminal window),

  ```
  cd /cdrom
  md5sum -c md5sum.txt | grep -v 'OK$'
  ```
- Check if there is some error.
- Edit your question to tell us which file causes an error output.

### Edit:

#### Conclusion

I ask again: Did you really check when running your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS laptop, that the checksum of the new iso file is correct? I suggest that you check again, when in the directory of the iso file,

```
<<<'b45165ed3cd437b9ffad02a2aad22a4ddc69162470e2622982889ce5826f6e3d *ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso' sha256sum -c
```

See details at [releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.1/](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.1/)

> When I tried installing again, it found an error in one file again. I
> installed ubuntu without problems, but before I set everything up, I'd
> like to know whether I should go through the whole process again and
> if so, how I can fix the error in the file.
>
> ETA following the instructions in the answer below I found that the
> non matching file is `./boot/grub/efi.img`

This file is part of the boot system of the live drive.

If the checksum above is correct and your installed system boots as it should boot, I think that there is nothing to worry about.

#### Call for second opinion

It is possible that the efi image file was modified during the boot due to some security action related to checking for the boothole bug. But I don't know the details, so if someone who reads this thinks there is a risk, please blow the whistle.

Comment: Thank you for the clear instructions. There were three (unrelated) things going on at the same time this morning, and I didn't do a grep on the results of the md5, just scrolled over them, so it could be that I missed them when I did the md5 checksum the first time. I'll try it again on my old laptop, to see if it was just me not paying enough attention.